# Label cut off when changing text using SWT

Tags: java, shell, label, swt

So I build a shell that looks like the following
[image]

After I click the change path button, I prompt for the path and then set the text. The problem is after doing so new text gets cut off if its too long like so. 
[image]

I am using a Label to display the path, and the only method I'm using in the listener regarding the Laebl is the setText() method. Is there a way to not have this happen? I am using SWT and prefer to maintain the grid layout so I can have the 2 columns. Any info would be helpful. Thank you.

Here's the code

```
String unit[] = {"Pixil", "Inch"};

                    final CustomAttribute realWidth = new CustomAttribute(String.valueOf(obj.getGraph().getWidth(null)));
                    final CustomAttribute realHeight = new CustomAttribute(String.valueOf(obj.getGraph().getHeight(null)));

                    double[] sizes = obj.convertToSizes();
                    if(sizes != null){
                        realWidth.setValue(sizes[0]);
                        realHeight.setValue(sizes[1]);
                    }

                    final Shell shell = new Shell(d);
                    shell.setImage(ApplicationPlugin.getImage(ApplicationPlugin.QUATTRO_ICON));
                    shell.setLayout(new org.eclipse.swt.layout.GridLayout(2,true));
                    shell.setText(EDIT_IMG_WINDOW_TITLE);

                    //width info
                    final Label labelWidth = new Label(shell, SWT.HORIZONTAL);
                    final Text textWidth = new Text(shell,SWT.SINGLE | SWT.BORDER);

                    //height info
                    final Label labelHeight = new Label(shell, SWT.HORIZONTAL);
                    final Text textHeight = new Text(shell,SWT.SINGLE | SWT.BORDER);

                    //units info
                    final Combo unitCombo = new Combo (shell, SWT.READ_ONLY);
                    final Button ratioBox = new Button (shell, SWT.CHECK);
                    ratioBox.setText(EDIT_IMG_RADIO);

                    //path info
                    final Button pathButton = new Button (shell, SWT.PUSH);
                    pathButton.setText(EDIT_IMG_PATH);
                    final Label pathText = new Label(shell, SWT.HORIZONTAL);
                    pathText.setText(obj.getTextData()[0]);

                    Button change = new Button (shell, SWT.PUSH);
                    change.setText(EDIT_IMG_SAVE_BUTTON);
                    ModifyListener heightListener = new ModifyListener(){
                        public void modifyText(ModifyEvent e) {
                            if(realImgListen && textHeight.getText() != ""){
                                realImgListen = false;
                                try{
                                    double oldHeight = realHeight.getDouble();
                                    double newHeight = Double.parseDouble(textHeight.getText());
                                    double oldWidth = Double.parseDouble(textWidth.getText());
                                    if(unitCombo.getSelectionIndex() == 1){
                                        newHeight = newHeight * designer.getPixilPerInch();
                                        oldWidth = oldWidth * designer.getPixilPerInch();
                                    }   
                                    realHeight.setValue(newHeight);
                                    double[] sizes = obj.convertToSizes();
                                    if(sizes != null)
                                        realWidth.setValue(sizes[0]);
                                    else
                                        realWidth.setValue(oldWidth);

                                    if(realHeight.getDouble() > SheetCanvas.sheetYSize)
                                        realHeight.setValue(SheetCanvas.sheetYSize);
                                    if(realHeight.getDouble() < 1)
                                        realHeight.setValue(1);

                                    if(ratioBox.getSelection() == true){
                                        double scale = Double.parseDouble(realHeight.getValue()) / oldHeight;
                                        realWidth.setValue(String.valueOf(realWidth.getDouble()*scale));
                                        if(unitCombo.getSelectionIndex() == 0)
                                            textWidth.setText(String.valueOf((int)Math.round(Double.parseDouble(realWidth.getValue()))));
                                        else
                                            textWidth.setText(String.valueOf(Double.parseDouble(realWidth.getValue())/designer.getPixilPerInch()));
                                    }
                                    obj.storeSizingInfo(realWidth.getDouble(), realHeight.getDouble(), 0);
                                    realImgListen = true;
                                }
                                catch(NumberFormatException e2){
                                    realImgListen = true;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    };
                    ModifyListener widthListener = new ModifyListener(){
                        public void modifyText(ModifyEvent e) {
                            if(realImgListen && textHeight.getText() != ""){
                                realImgListen = false;
                                try{
                                    double oldWidth = realWidth.getDouble();
                                    double newWidth = Double.parseDouble(textWidth.getText());
                                    double oldHeight = Double.parseDouble(textHeight.getText());
                                    if(unitCombo.getSelectionIndex() == 1){
                                        newWidth = newWidth * designer.getPixilPerInch();
                                        oldHeight = oldHeight * designer.getPixilPerInch();
                                    }   
                                    realWidth.setValue(newWidth);
                                    double[] sizes = obj.convertToSizes();
                                    if(sizes != null)
                                        realHeight.setValue(sizes[1]);
                                    else
                                        realHeight.setValue(oldHeight);

                                    if(realWidth.getDouble() > SheetCanvas.sheetYSize)
                                        realWidth.setValue(SheetCanvas.sheetYSize);
                                    if(realWidth.getDouble() < 1)
                                        realWidth.setValue(1);

                                    if(ratioBox.getSelection() == true){
                                        double scale = Double.parseDouble(realWidth.getValue()) / oldWidth;
                                        realHeight.setValue(String.valueOf(realHeight.getDouble()*scale));
                                        if(unitCombo.getSelectionIndex() == 0)
                                            textHeight.setText(String.valueOf((int)Math.round(Double.parseDouble(realHeight.getValue()))));
                                        else
                                            textHeight.setText(String.valueOf(Double.parseDouble(realHeight.getValue())/designer.getPixilPerInch()));
                                    }
                                    obj.storeSizingInfo(realWidth.getDouble(), realHeight.getDouble(), 0);
                                    realImgListen = true;
                                }
                                catch(NumberFormatException e2){
                                    realImgListen = true;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    };
                    textHeight.addModifyListener(heightListener);
                    textWidth.addModifyListener(widthListener);
                    unitCombo.addSelectionListener(new SelectionAdapter() {
                        @Override
                        public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent e) {
                            realImgListen = false;
                            if(unitCombo.getSelectionIndex() == 0){
                                textWidth.setText(String.valueOf((int)Math.rint(realWidth.getDouble())));
                                textHeight.setText(String.valueOf((int)Math.rint(realHeight.getDouble())));
                            }
                            else{
                                textWidth.setText(String.valueOf(realWidth.getDouble()/designer.getPixilPerInch()));
                                textHeight.setText(String.valueOf(realHeight.getDouble()/designer.getPixilPerInch()));
                            }
                            realImgListen = true;
                        }
                    });
                    change.addSelectionListener(new SelectionAdapter() {
                        @Override
                        public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent e) {

                            Double width = realWidth.getDouble();
                            Double height = realHeight.getDouble();

                            String line1;
                            if(obj.getTextData() != null)
                                line1 = obj.getTextData()[0];
                            else
                                line1 = null;
                            String[] textData = {line1,null};
                            obj.setTextData(textData);
                            obj.storeSizingInfo(Math.rint(width), Math.rint(height),0);
                            designer.updateDataFromSource(settings);
                            designer.repaint();
                            updatePanelButtons();
                            shell.close();
                        }
                    });
                    pathButton.addSelectionListener(new SelectionAdapter() {
                        @Override
                        public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent e) {
                            //path button
                            String path = null;
                            path = getPathFromBrowser(FILE_CHOOSER_IMAGE_TITLE_STR,DEFAULT_PATH,acceptedImgFormats,null,SWT.OPEN);
                            pathText.setText(path);
                            if(path != null){
                                String[] paths = settings.getCustomImagePath();
                                int pathIndex = 0;
                                for(int i = 0; i < paths.length; i++){
                                    if(obj.getTextData()[0].equals(paths[i]))
                                        pathIndex = i;
                                }
                                paths[pathIndex] = path;
                                settings.setCustomImagePath(paths);
                                paths = settings.getCustomImageChoices();
                                paths[pathIndex] = getFileNameFromPath(path);
                                settings.setCustomImageChoices(paths);
                                designer.updateDataFromSource(settings);
                                String[] textData = obj.getTextData();
                                textData[0] = path;
                                if(textData.length > 1)
                                    textData[1] = null;
                                obj.setTextData(textData);
                            }
                        }
                    });

                    textWidth.setTextLimit(7);
                    textHeight.setTextLimit(7);
                    labelWidth.setText(EDIT_IMG_WIDTH);
                    labelHeight.setText(EDIT_IMG_HEIGHT);
                    unitCombo.setItems(unit);
                    unitCombo.select(0);
                    ratioBox.setSelection(true);
                    org.eclipse.swt.graphics.Rectangle clientArea = shell.getClientArea();
                    unitCombo.setBounds(clientArea.x, clientArea.y, 300, 200);
                    shell.pack();
                    shell.open();
                    Shell shellTemp = SWT_AWT.new_Shell(d, designer);
                    Monitor primary = d.getPrimaryMonitor();
                    org.eclipse.swt.graphics.Rectangle bounds = primary.getBounds();
                    org.eclipse.swt.graphics.Rectangle rect = shell.getBounds();
                    int x = bounds.x + (bounds.width - rect.width) / 2;
                    int y = bounds.y + (bounds.height - rect.height) / 2;
                    shell.setLocation(x, y);
                    shell.moveAbove(shellTemp);
                    shellTemp.dispose();
                    shell.addListener(SWT.Close, new Listener() {
                        @Override  
                        public void handleEvent(Event event) {
                            editingImg();
                          }
                        });
                    realImgListen = false;
                    textWidth.setText(String.valueOf((int)Double.parseDouble(realWidth.getValue())));
                    textHeight.setText(String.valueOf((int)Double.parseDouble(realHeight.getValue())));
                    realImgListen = true;
```

Comment: the text is taller than your label, you can increase the size of your label this can help you

Comment: can you put your code please?

Comment: Are you using `Layout`s at all?

Comment: I'm using a grid layout

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The width of your columns is currently being set to the width of the widest control - probably 'Maintain Image Ratio'. If you set the the path text to anything longer than that it will be truncated.

You could set a width hint on the path control to set its size:

```
GridData data = new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.CENTER, true, false);
data.widthHint = 100;  // You choose the width
pathText.setLayoutData(data);
```

Note that you have specified that the columns are of equal width so this will add similar space to the first column. You might want to switch to unequal width columns.

Alternatively you can ask the `Shell` to recalculate the size after you set the new text. Just call:

```
 shell.pack();
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like that you are redrawing the change path label components and you are not  wrapping the label .
That why at the time of redrawing some part of the text is not visible.

Use warping or you can also increase the screen size

Comment: The screen size has no effect on the cut off, what is warping?